# problem in updating state using useState hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am using useSatate for managing my form errors:

```
const [formErrorObj, updateForErrormObj] = useState({
        name_error: '',
        email_error: '',
        contact_number_error: '',
        username_error: '',
        password_error: '',
        promo_mail_error: ''
    })
```

and this is where I am creating object with all form errors:

```
function onSubmitHandler(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const error = validate();
        if (error) {
        const errorList = error.error.details;
        const newErrorObj = {};
        for (let err in errorList) {
            newErrorObj[error.error.details[err].context.key + '_error'] = error.error.details[err].message

        }
        updateForErrormObj({ ...formErrorObj, ...newErrorObj })

        console.log(newErrorObj, formErrorObj)
    }
}
```

Newly created object looks something like this :

```
contact_number_error: ""Contact Number" is not allowed to be empty"
email_error: ""Email" must be a valid email"
name_error: ""Username" is not allowed to be empty"
password_error: ""Password" length must be at least 5 characters long"
username_error: ""Username" is not allowed to be empty"
__proto__: Object
```

After validation when I try to update state using :

```
updateForErrormObj({ newErrorObj }) // try 1 
updateForErrormObj(newErrorObj) // try 2
updateForErrormObj({ ...formErrorObj, ...newErrorObj }) // try 3
```

no try from three works form me.
I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? The state remains the same as the initial state?

Comment: @wentjun yes, same as initial state

Comment: Where are you trying to update this? Is it a `useEffect` or a callback function? Also, how did you confirm it was not being updated

Comment: And how is this state being updated? Mind posting the relevant code?

Comment: @Agney I am not using `useEffect` Please check updated question to check steps. `console.log(newErrorObj, formErrorObj)` this line confirms me that state is not updated

Comment: @wentjun please check updated code

Comment: setting state is an [async process](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous), you cannot log directly below it to see updated state.

Comment: @Agney got the issue, how can I use callback with update useState ?

Comment: @ParitoshMahale Did not catch the question, if you just want to see updated state, you can either log in a `useEffect` with `formErrorObj` as dependency or in render(more noisy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean by it does not update because you console.log it. It is how it works, it is async. You can check it by console.log in the `useEffect`, so you can see it actually does update.